# How to detect new methods in JAXB classes

Tags: java, xml, eclipse, jaxb

Good afternoon,

I'm working with a large xml schema that is subject to many changes. Currently I'm using JAXB to handle it, and was wondering if there was a way to see if any additional methods are added to the JAXB classes based off of the schema changes. All of the JAXB methods should be called somewhere throughout the project, but not necessarily at run time, so things like EclEmma don't really work for me. I just want a simple way to double check that all of the possible xml tags are handled. An example might give some more clarity.

Example:

```
<!-- before schema change -->
<School>
    <Student>Kyle</Student>
</School>

<!-- after schema change -->
<School>
    <Student>Kyle</Student>
    <NewStudent>Susan</NewStudent>
</School>
```

I would like to have a way to be notified that the "NewStudent" field has been added to the schema and JAXB, but not handled yet in my java project. Is there any tool in the Eclipse Marketplace that would help me?

I can't rely on any external libraries so this functionality needs to come from Eclipse or be written by myself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best solution for my issue is to use the UCDetector plugin found here http://www.ucdetector.org/

I would then run the plugin on the JAXB package exclusively while filtering out the setters, or any other methods I don't care if I use or not.